# How to add Crosshair using ThreeJS, React

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

In VR Canvas the pointer is placed in the middle of the screen. But it is difficult to identify its exact location of it. To mitigate this we can use Crosshair same as the shooting games. But how can we add a Crosshair to React app that used the ThreeJS and React-three-fiber.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a popular answer: https://codepen.io/driezis/pen/jOPzjLG

and here is my custom code, Enjoy...

```
import {useFrame, useThree} from "@react-three/fiber";
import {useEffect, useRef} from "react";
import {Line, Vector3} from "three";

const Crosshair = () => {
    const dot = useRef();
    const lines = useRef();
    const { camera } = useThree();

    useFrame(() => {
        const vector = new Vector3(0, 0, -0.8).unproject(camera);
        dot.current.position.set(...vector.toArray());
        camera.add(lines.current);
        lines.current.position.set(0, 0, -4);
    })

    const Line = (props) => {
        const ref = useRef()

        useEffect(() => {
            if(ref.current){
                ref.current.geometry.setFromPoints([props.start, props.end].map((point) => new Vector3(...point)));
            }
        });

        return (
            <line ref={ref}>
                <bufferGeometry />
                <lineBasicMaterial color="white"/>
            </line>
        )
    }

    return (
        <group>
            <group ref={lines}>
                <Line start={[0.05,0,0]} end={[0.18,0,0]} />
                <Line start={[0,0.05,0]} end={[0,0.18,0]} />
                <Line start={[-0.05,0,0]} end={[-0.18,0,0]} />
                <Line start={[0,-0.05,0]} end={[0,-0.18,0]} />
            </group>
            <mesh ref={dot}>
                <sphereBufferGeometry args={[0.0005, 64, 32]} />
                <meshBasicMaterial color={'red'} />
            </mesh>
        </group>
    )
}

export default Crosshair;
```

Comment: I like it, but looks like the lines aren't appearing. Also, do you know if there is any way to stop it flickering when a user moves? (I'm trying it with this: https://codesandbox.io/s/vkgi6)